# I believe this Perl script is secure. Can it be improved?

Tags: regex, perl, security

I have the following Perl script. One can (not right now because I just took it down) ping a URL like

```
http://www.joereddington.com/testsound/getsound.pl?text=hello%20mum
```

and then find that the file

```
http://www.joereddington.com/testsound/hope.wav
```

is a recording of a computer voice saying "hello mum".

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI qw(:standard -debug);

my $text = param('text');
$text =~ s/[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]//g;

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

system("/home8/projedf4/tts/espeak-1.48.04-source/src/speak \"$text\" -w hope.wav");
```

I'm a little nervous about having users possibly take advantage of injection attacks and the like. I believe I've done enough with the line

```
$text =~ s/[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]//g;
```

because I'm just extracting literally everything that could do damage from the string.

But is this enough? I could even go as far as

```
$text =~ s/[^0-9a-zA-Z\s\.,]//g;
```

Comment: One improvement would be to pass the arguments to `system` as an array, so that Perl would not use the shell at all, but would execute the program directly.  You might do better to replace series of one or more of the verboten characters (not allowed characters) with a space, to preserve 'word' spacing in the text, but that's separate from the security.

Comment: It is also a good idea to use perl's taint mode when writing CGI scripts (so the interpreter will enforce that you are checking your inputs).

Comment: Use perl in [taint mode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Taint-mode).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, your code is fine (ignoring bugs in `perl`, `speak`, DOS attacks, etc.), assuming the only arguments that are special to `speak` start with `-`.

But it can be improved.

1. There's no need to remove so many characters.

   ```
   sub shell_quote {
      return map {
         die if /\x00/;
         my $lit = $_;
         $lit =~ s/'/'\\''/g;
         "'$lit'"              
      } @_;
   }

   $text =~ s/^-+//;
   system(shell_quote('/.../speak', $text, '-w', 'hope.wav'));
   ```

   or

   ```
   use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

   $text =~ s/^-+//;
   system(shell_quote('/.../speak', $text, '-w', 'hope.wav'));
   ```
2. There's no need to launch a shell too.

   ```
   die if $text =~ /\x00/;
   $text =~ s/^-+//;
   system('/.../speak', $text, '-w', 'hope.wav');
   ```
3. If your `speak` supports `--`, you could even use

   ```
   die if $text =~ /\x00/;
   system('/.../speak', '-w', 'hope.wav', '--', $text);
   ```

Comment: That's excellent - thank you. I might need a little bit of explanation of what the regex $text =~ /\x00/ is?

Comment: @Joe: `"\x00"` is the NUL character. It is a menace because standard C code regards it as a string terminator